# Send-MailMessage -From - bad formatting

Tags: powershell

Quite simple question. I'm sending an email with `send-mailmessage`, which works fine. But i'm not entirely happy with the format of the sender.

```
Send-MailMessage -to "User01 <User01@example.com>" -from "USER02 <USER02@example.com>" -subject "Test mail" -SmtpServer 'mysmtp'
```

When receiving the Mail (IBM Lotus Notes) the sender is shown as "user02" in lower case, although i'm running the command with the sender in upper case - as shown above.
Is there by purpose any simple way to solve my little problem? Should be shown as "USER02" not as "user02". Reason of Powershell or cause of Lotus Notes?

Comment: It's fairly easy to investigate, just [inspect the message's headers](http://www.matnewman.com/webs/personal/matblog.nsf/dx/how-to-view-message-headers-in-lotus-notes?opendocument&comments) and see if the From header is all lowercase or not

Comment: Thanks for this information.
In the page source it's already shown, that the sender-mailadress is already in lower case
"From: user02@example.com"
exactly what i do not want

Comment: You file a bug on Microsoft Connect :)